All materials appear black in the preview render (EEVEE 4.3)
While I was modeling in Blender 4.3, I switched to material preview mode to texture it, but the models appear to be black. I wanted to make sure that this wasn’t universal, so I went to version 4.0 (the latest version of Blender I have before 4.3) and noticed that the mistake didn’t persist, and that the models retain their original textures.
(The image at the top is 4.0 while the image at the bottom is 4.3)
This just happened today, as any other day the model would appear either it's default white or with a visible material or texture applied. The only way I could circumvent this in eevee was to enable raytracing settings and either disable Fast GIU Approximation or slide the treshold all the way to 1.00, but I'm not one to continuosly use raytracing if I simply want to view materials. Does anyone else have this problem and is there a way to fix this?



